# Get Name of User from Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I need to show only the name of a user from Active Directory, I am using

```
 lbl_Login.Text = User.Identity.Name; //the result is domain\username
```

This shows the users name but not the real name of the user, I've checked other questions and answers related here but I've not gotten the solution.

Is there any property just as "User.Identity.Name" to get only the name of the user?

Comment: I will post a simple way to get the full display name

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want name of a user from active directory. Try code like this:

```
string name ="";
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    var usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name); 
    if (usr != null)
       name = usr.DisplayName;  
}
```

or this from [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54ab2baa-c777-4171-8367-32292db3a096/how-to-get-the-display-name-of-the-current-user?forum=csharpgeneral):

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
string displayName = user.DisplayName;
```

or may be it:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
```

> The [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) provides uniform access and manipulation of user, computer, and group security principals across the multiple principal stores: Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS), Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS), and Machine SAM (MSAM).

Comment: Not true @MethodMan, sure Response.Write or Debug.Write is more common but you can still use Console output.

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement more slow than DirectoryEntry ?

Comment: @Kiquenet I can't answer to your question because I didn't check it.

Comment: @DenisBubnov using the same code. how can i fetch that user phone number.?
Right-now i getting Email id  by using this code (email= usr.EmailAddress;)

Comment: Which namespace is "User" from?

Comment: Namespace:System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Comment: What is the purpose of `PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);` in the second code snippet? It seems ctx isn't used there.

Answer (score 6):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

string fullName = null;
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            fullName = user.DisplayName;
            lbl_Login.Text = fullName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked too,  I just had to add replace "User.Identity.Name" to where you placed manually my  users name